Exportar informacion de un datagridview a excel
Hola me podrían ayudar por favor con el siguiente código, en la imagen esta el error
private void ExportToExcel(DataGridView dataGridView)    
{

     Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
     excelApp.Visible = true;

     Workbook workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add();

     Worksheet worksheet = (Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];
     int columnsCount = dataGridView.ColumnCount;
     for (int i = 0; i < columnsCount; i++)
     {
         worksheet.Cells[1, i + 1] = dataGridView.Columns[i].HeaderText;

     }
     int rowsCount = dataGridView.RowCount;
     for (int i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++)
     {
         for (int j = 0; j < columnsCount; j++)
         {
             worksheet.Cells[1 + 2, j + 1] = dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value;
         }
     }
     string tempFile = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName() + ".xls";
     workbook.SaveAs(tempFile);
 }



Yo lo realizo de esta manera y siempre me ha funcionado, tal vez a ti te ayude
  private void ReporteaExcel() {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        Page pagina = new Page();
        HtmlForm form = new HtmlForm();
        gvdatos.EnableViewState = false;//GRIDVIEW
        pagina.EnableEventValidation = false;
        pagina.DesignerInitialize();
        pagina.Controls.Add(form);
        form.Controls.Add(gvdatos);
        pagina.RenderControl(htw);
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=REPORTE ACTIVOS PENDIENTES DE MANTENIMIENTO.xls");
        Response.Charset = "UTF-8";
        Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.Default;
        Response.Write(sb.ToString());
        Response.End();

}


Muchas gracias, lo voy a intentar
